# mysql sum of record between each session of day from timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in database which has the following columns

```
id, timestamp,user_id
```

I want to pass two dates and it should find the sum of the records. for example i pass `from = 01-12-2014 and 15-12-2014` and it should show a record like

```
00-04    5
04-08    40
08-12    30
12-16    20
16-20    32
20-24    50
```

Comment: what are `00-04`, `04-08`, etc?

Comment: Provide the sample data in the table

Comment: id      login_timestamp         user_id
1        1383647374                 5
2         1383647374                10
3         1383647374                20

Comment: 00-04 and 04-08 are the sessions in the day.  eg. 00-04  time between 00 and 04 am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should group by date and count or sum after your records column something like : "select sum(records) from db_table group by added_date"

For every distinct date he will add/count ( depends on what you want ) the records.

Comment: you could format that timestamp using 
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x')...

This will format date as     -> '2007 30th November 10:30:59 2007''

Comment: is there any way i can convert timestamp column into date in where clause.  At the moment the timestamp column has unix timestamps and i want to query in way   where  timestamp  between y-m-d and y-m-d
and the timestamp should convert to y-m-d during runtime only

Comment: Yes, just use that function with a proper format for you query. Try to use the function with BETWEEN function(timestamp,format) and function(timestamp,format) and then in GROUP BY for unique results.

Comment: Thank you it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

i used a loop to increase time by 14400 and the query is following

select count(id) as sessions from user_history where date_format(login_timestamp, '%d-%m-%Y') < date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(1157065200), '%d-%m-%Y') and date(login_timestamp) > date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(1157079600), '%d-%m-%Y') and date_format(login_timestamp, '%H:%i:%s') <= date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(1157065200), '%H:%i:%s')